# using pi zero as a wireless microphone for voice recognition

Tags: speech-recognition

I would like to be able to talk to a pi zero in one room send that audio to a Pi 3 to be interpreted there on the jasper speech recognition system and sent back to the pi zero to be executed.  I would like to know if there is a way to do this without having an internet connection (except for installation) so the jasper system or a similar alternative is a must.

Jasper: http://jasperproject.github.io/

Comment: You could use bluetooth, which I think will be significantly more complicated.   You would probably be much better off using wifi with one of them set up as an access point (meaning, no other network is required).

Comment: Just install prosdy XAMPP based chat server and install jabber based(most phones support or has it) messenger and talk from any room over wifi .